# Example of joint submission to PRL, PRA

Tags: publications, physics, publishability

We are thinking about a joint submission to Physical Review Letters, and PRA per [these guidelines](https://journals.aps.org/prl/edannounce/10.1103/PhysRevLett.118.240001). I'm however not entirely sure how the two submissions should be exactly related, e.g. how much overlap the works may have.

Does anybody have some insights here? Or just a few example papers that have been jointly published like this.

Comment: One should note that the "companion" paper - though not an official policy - was rather common before PRL introduced supplemental material.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recently, I've been considering a PRL-PRB joint submission, and was looking for recent examples. It appears there is no external marker for them, so they can indeed be hard to find. My initial web searches led me to this question, and to a [Twitter thread](https://twitter.com/RobertGaristo/status/1141436299313856513) by a PRL editor actually providing some examples.

One way I came up with, that finds at least some examples, is to search Google for

```
"companion paper Phys. Rev. A" site:journals.aps.org/prl
```

replace "A" as needed. (This search matches how the reference tends to be formatted.)

For reference, some examples of joint submissions are:

- PRLs with companion PRAs: [1](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.126.110403), [2](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.126.063001), [3](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.123.183001)
- PRLs with companion PRBs: [1](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.122.246403), [2](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.125.157403)
- PRLs with companion PRCs: [1](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.125.202702), [2](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.125.102501)
- PRLs with companion PRDs: [1](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.125.242001), [2](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.125.231601)
- PRLs with companion PREs: [1](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.125.100602), [2](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.123.268001)

These examples demonstrate that the overlap between letter and full-length article is somewhat variable, reflecting the nature of the results and how well they "split up". Nevertheless, a fairly representative case that I think handled the splitting well in a [PRL](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.126.110403)-[PRA](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.103.032424) joint submission wrote:

> LETTER: We present a self-contained discussion of our methods and results below. The full technical details and additional developments are deferred to the companion paper [52], where we consider the problem of quantifying infinite-dimensional resources from a broader perspective of general probabilistic theories, extending the concepts discussed herein.

> PAPER Intro: This work also serves as the companion to the paper [39] which deals with resource quantification in continuous-variable quantum mechanics. Here we provide a derivation and extended discussion of the results stated in [39], along with several additional developments specific to quantum theory. The general framework in GPTs can be thought of as a generalization of the concepts introduced in [39].

> PAPER Sec. VI:
> This section complements the dedicated paper [39] in which we focus on the case of continuous-variable quantum resources. In particular, the discussion below constitutes a
> technical companion to Ref. [39], providing a detailed derivation and several extensions of the results mentioned there. Since all of our results for general GTPs immediately apply to quantum mechanics as a special case, the results of previous sections already serve as proofs of some of the results of [39]. Specifically, Theorem 1 in [39] is Theorem 10 here; Theorem 2 in [39] is Theorem 9 here; Theorem 3 in [39] is a consequence of our characterization in Sec. III and in particular the duality result in Prop. 2. The other results will be established below.

Answer (score -3):

Even if the journal permits it, publishing one work as two papers is viewed as dubiously ethical in the scientific community.  I recommend doing a joint submission only if the scope of the two papers is obviously different.

Also, it's a lot of trouble considering 75% of PRLs get rejected, and you can't take your joint submission to another publisher.